# Can't get overflow menu into CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to get the overflow settings menu to appear, but I can't. I'd like it to appear after the collapse... but at this point I would be happy to have it be persistent. I have the toolbar here wired in the Activity the same way as another one where it works just fine. The only thing that shows up here is the back button.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:elevation="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ed"
                android:id="@+id/expandedCardIMageView" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_expanded"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Completely forgot
    @Override
    onCreateOptionsMenu....

Answer (score 0):

Completely forgot

```
@Override onCreateOptionsMenu....
```